# How to set timeout on socket receive vc++ mfc

Tags: c++, sockets, visual-c++, mfc

I have created a server in `MFC`. Client is connected to server and server is waiting for receiving data, which is sent by the client.
I want a timeout period for receiving `pSocket.Receive(cbuf,1)`.
Here is my code :

```
 int i_userid; AfxSocketInit(); bool    bRun = true;    
 CWinThread *pCurrentThread; pCurrentThread = AfxGetThread();

 SOCKET   pCurrentHandle; CSocket pSocket; pCurrentHandle =hClinetHandle;


  pSocket.Attach(hClinetHandle);    

    LeaveCriticalSection(&m_socket_lock); CSocket t_socket; 

    CString  m_Ipadd=L""; UINT m_portno=0;              
    pSocket.GetPeerName(m_Ipadd,m_portno);

    st_Client* m_st_Client=new  st_Client();    

    //receive Use Id and Get UserPortfolio CString m_token=L"";

    CString New_data=L"";char cbuf[24]; 
    for(int i=0;i<24;i++) 
    cbuf[i] ='\0';      

    while(bRun) 
    {               
        if(pSocket.Receive(cbuf,1)>0) 
        {   
            New_data=cbuf;      
            if(wcscmp(New_data,L"\r")==0 ||wcscmp(New_data,L"|")==0)
            {           
               break;       
            }
            m_token=m_token+New_data;
        } 
        else
        {
          bRun=false; 
          break;
        }               
    }
```

some other code of CTimeout but it didn't work there.........

```
void CServerSocket::OnAccept(int nErrorCode) 
{

    m_Client.m_hSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    AfxMessageBox("Client Request Connection");

    if(!SetTimeOut(10000))
    {
      ASSERT(FALSE);
     // Error Handling...for some reason, we could not setup
     // the timer.
    }

    if(!Accept(m_Client))
    {
        int nError = GetLastError();
        if(nError==WSAEINTR)
            AfxMessageBox("No Connections Arrived For 10 Seconds");
        else
            ; // Do other error processing.
    }

    CSocket::OnAccept(nErrorCode);
}
```

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/138692/how-to-configure-a-time-out-on-a-csocket-operation

Comment: thank you but i used it already and  it didn't work.

Comment: You have to use `CSocket::CancelBlockingCall` function to come out of receive. I don't think your posted code does anything good.It it has not even waited to `accept` call from client. If you have tried implementation of `CTimeOutSocket` then please share your code and I'll guide to fix this issue.

Comment: [`WSACancelBlockingCall()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741547.aspx) doesn't even exist in WinSock 2.x, only WinSock 1.x. Consider the option to simply stop using `CSocket` and use the WinSock API directly instead, then you can configure the socket to run in non-blocking mode. Or use `select()`/`WSAEventSelect()`/`WSAAsyncSelect()` to implement timeouts. Or use Overlapped I/O, or an I/O Completion Port.  There are many different ways to use sockets on Windows without blocking threads, and `CSocket` is not one of them.

Comment: thanks you but i am new in csocket mfc can you please explain me how to implement WSACancelBlockingCall()  in csocket.